# How to resize a control inside a TFlowPanel using the Align property?

Tags: delphi, flowpanel

I have a few controls (namely, `TDBChart`) inside a `TFlowPanel`. When the user clicks on one of them, I'd like it to fill the entire `flow panel`'s client area. But, it seems that changing the `visible` and `align` property of child controls inside a `flow panel` at run time doesn't have any effect. Is there a special trick to this? I found the `Realign()` method, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the control's layout. Here's the code to my `OnClick` event:

```
var
  AChart: TDBChart;
  V: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
begin
  AChart := TDBChart(Sender);
  if AChart.Align = alNone then
  begin
    V := False;
    AChart.Align := alClient;
  end else begin
    V := True;
    AChart.Align := alNone;
  end;
  for i := 0 to FlowPanel1.ControlCount - 1 do
    if FlowPanel1.Controls[i] is TDBChart then
      if FlowPanel1.Controls[i] <> AChart then
        FlowPanel1.Controls[i].Visible := V;
end;
```

The charts are hidden or shown as expected, but `ADBChart` doesn't fill the entire `flow panel`'s client area.

Comment: Nice _"zooming in on a FlowPanel"_-question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FlowPanel does not care its controls' alignment settings, much like it doesn't care for their position - it is designed only to flow them.

One solution can be to derive a new class and override `AlignControls`, and in it, resize the control that would fill the surface accordingly. As an example:

```
type
  TFlowPanel = class(extctrls.TFlowPanel)
  protected
    procedure AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect); override;
  end;

..

procedure TFlowPanel.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
var
  i, VisibleCount, VisibleControl: Integer;
begin
  VisibleCount := 0;
  VisibleControl := 0;
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i].Visible then begin
      Inc(VisibleCount);
      VisibleControl := i;
    end;

  if (VisibleCount = 1) and (Controls[VisibleControl] = AControl) and
      (AControl.Align = alClient) then begin
    // preserve 'Explicit..' settings
    AControl.ControlState := AControl.ControlState + [csAligning];
    AControl.SetBounds(1, 1, ClientWidth - 1, ClientHeight -1);
    AControl.ControlState := AControl.ControlState - [csAligning];
  end;

  inherited;
end;
```

Then you can set all of your charts' click event to this handler:

```
var
  AChart: TTDBChart;

  procedure SetVisibility(Visible: Boolean);
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to FlowPanel1.ControlCount - 1 do
      if FlowPanel1.Controls[i] is TDBChart then
        if FlowPanel1.Controls[i] <> AChart then
          FlowPanel1.Controls[i].Visible := Visible;
  end;

begin
  AChart := TDBChart(Sender);
  if AChart.Align = alNone then
  begin
    SetVisibility(False);
    AChart.Align := alClient;
  end else begin
    AChart.Align := alNone; // set before changing visible
    SetVisibility(True);
    AChart.SetBounds(0, 0, AChart.ExplicitWidth, AChart.ExplicitHeight);
  end;
end;
```

I should note that this is only good for a fixed sized flowpanel.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I had to hard code `AChart.ExplicitWidth` and `AChart.ExplicitHeight`. Thanks

Comment: @iMan - > *"..had to hard code.."* > Then you can remove the 'ControlState :=' statements from 'AlignControls'. Or, on the contrary, you can try setting the flag in the click handler while setting the alignment and visibility.   Anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As by design, `T(Custom)FlowPanel` uses customized aligning of child controls, which is implemented in an overriden `AlignControls` method.

You can prevent this default behaviour by *skipping* it, falling back on that from its ancestor. Also, hiding all adjacent controls is not necessary. Bringing the clicked chart to front will suffice.

```
type
  TFlowPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TFlowPanel)
  private
    FFlowDisabled: Boolean;
    procedure SetFlowDisabled(Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect); override;
  public
    property FlowDisabled: Boolean read FFlowDisabled write SetFlowDisabled;
  end;

...

{ TFlowPanel }

type
  TWinControlAccess = class(TWinControl);
  TAlignControls = procedure(Instance: TObject; AControl: TControl;
    var Rect: TRect);

procedure TFlowPanel.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
  if FFlowDisabled then
    // Skip inherited in TCustomFlowPanel:
    TAlignControls(@TWinControlAccess.AlignControls)(Self, AControl, Rect)
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TFlowPanel.SetFlowDisabled(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FFlowDisabled <> Value then
  begin
    FFlowDisabled := Value;
    Realign;
  end;
end;    

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.DBChartClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  FlowAligns: array[Boolean] of TAlign = (alNone, alClient);
var
  Chart: TDBChart;
  Panel: TFlowPanel;
  DisableFlow: Boolean;
begin
  Chart := TDBChart(Sender);
  Panel := Chart.Parent as TFlowPanel;
  DisableFlow := not Panel.FlowDisabled;
  Chart.Align := FlowAligns[DisableFlow];
  Chart.BringToFront;
  Panel.FlowDisabled := DisableFlow;
end;
```

Comment: I guess this would also take care of a resizeable flowpanel.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, I tested it with all its anchors turned on.